# Misbehavior of div when tring to animate in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I trying to animate a small child div inside a parent div. And the animation is to move the child div -60px upwards when mouse enter to parent div and child div will return to its original position when mouse leave the parent div. And its working properly.
    But When the mouse move directly towards the child div it  move up but get down before  mouse leaving from the parent div. Please help me to solve this issue

See [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/FE3jD/)

My html code is

```
<div id="box" align="center">
    <div id="minibox"></div>
</div>
```

css code is

```
#box {
    position:relative;
    top:100px;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
}
#minibox {
    position:relative;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid #333;
    background-color:green;
}
```

jquery code is

```
$("#box").mouseenter(function () {
    ("#minibox").animate({
        top: "-60px"
    }, {
        duration: 180
    });
});
$("#box").mouseout(function () {
    $("#minibox").animate({
        top: "0px"
    }, {
        duration: 180
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry but it's just no fun too look at your code. not even using spaces

Comment: Why am I hit with the mental image of an `<h1>` spanking a `<div>` and telling it what a naughty element it's been? XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mouseleave instead of mouseout.

```
$("#box").mouseleave(function(){...});
```

Comment: Thanks, Now its working good. Now i have two set of div's to animate , div A,a and B,b. I need to animate div A and a when mouse enter to the first 'box' div and div B and b  when mouse enter to second 'box' div. Now the problem is that i can't able to animate them separately. please help me to do that. check this link (http://jsfiddle.net/josephpaul/ZKCuY/3/)

Answer (score 1):

This kind of thing should NOT be done with jQuery.

Raw CSS:

```css
#minibox { /* you can merge this with existing styles */
    top:0;
    transition: top 180ms ease;
    -webkit-transition: top 180ms ease;
}
#box:hover #minibox {
    top:-60px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jCYW8/)

Answer (score 0):

The miniboy is a parent of the box, so the mouse-event will be executed by overing the minbox too.
try this:

```
if($(e.target).closest('#minibox').length)
```

or: http://jsfiddle.net/FE3jD/7/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must be more specific on what happens in each case.
Made this simple example, http://jsfiddle.net/blackjim/FE3jD/13/

```
var $box = $("#box"),
    $minibox = $("#minibox"),
    animationIsDone = false,
    miniBoxMoved = false,
    onDone;

$minibox.mouseenter(function (e) {
    if (miniBoxMoved) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});

$box.mouseenter(function () {
    animationIsDone = false;
    miniBoxMoved = true;

    $minibox.animate({
        top: "-60px"
    }, {
        duration: 180,
        complete: function () {
            animationIsDone = true; // animation ended
            if (typeof onDone === 'function') {
                onDone();
            }
        }
    });

});

$box.mouseleave(function () {

    if (animationIsDone) {
        whenOutOfBox(); // call directly our callback
        onDone = ''; // not needed now
    } else {
        onDone = whenOutOfBox; //    pass it to the animation ending
    }
});


var whenOutOfBox = function () {
    $minibox.animate({
        top: "0px"
    }, {
        duration: 180,
        complete: function () {
            miniBoxMoved = false;
        }
    });
};
```